# Is it possible to write an asynchronous loop inside synchronous function?

Tags: rust, async-await, infinite-loop

This is my current Rust code

```
async fn test() {
    ........
    loop {
        ......
        set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    }
}
```

I want to make my function synchronous, can I do something like ...

```
fn test() {
    loop {
        async {
            ......
            set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something as shown above, I removed async keyword from the function and created an async block inside loop, but after this changes, my code somehow becomes unreachable,

How can I keep my "test" function synchronous and still make my code reachable?!

Comment: it's always possible to go from `async` to `sync`, the contrary is not possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code with the `async` block is unreachable since an `async` block does not *execute* the code inside, rather it *creates a future* that *when will be `.await`ed* will execute the code inside.

To execute an asynchronous code inside a synchronous function you need to block. The functions for that are usually provided by the async runtime you use. For example, tokio has [`block_on()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.block_on) (and a bunch of other functions). You do it like:

```rust
tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().handle().block_on(async {
    // ...
});
// Or by re-using the current runtime, if you have an active one:
tokio::runtime::Handle::current().block_on(async {
    // ...
});
```

There is a runtime-agnostic [`block_on()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/executor/fn.block_on.html) function provided by the `futures` crate, although using it is likely to be less performant and/or interfere with the runtime.

Note that blocking while you're executing asynchronous code (if the outer function is called by async code) is bad and may have serious implications.